# Accumulating Data in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, accumulate

I have a large PGA Tour data set (2312 obs. 18 variables) that has all player stats from 2010-2018. Looks something like this:

```
Player.Name      | Rounds | Fairway.Percentages |  Year   | Avg. Distance 
Henrick Stenson      60           75.19            2018        291.50
Henrick Stenson      65           70.09            2013        290.90
```

And it goes on for each player, so each row is a players statistics for that specific year. I want to accumulate the data for each player, so each player only shows up once, and show the 8 year average of each statistic over the time period of 2010-2018 so it looks like this

```
Player.Name      | Rounds| Fairway.Percentages |  Year   | Avg. Distance 
Henrick Stenson   *8yr avg      *8yr avg                      *8yr avg 
Jordan Spieth     *8yr avg      *8yr avg                      *8yr avg 
Rickie Fowler     *8yr avg      *8yr avg                      *8yr avg
```

I want to do this so I can perform a cluster analysis and cluster the players based on their stats (Long ball hitters, short accurate hitters, the best putters, etc...)

I know there is a rollmean function but was hoping I wouldnt have to do it for each individual column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  group_by(Player.Name) %>%
  summarize(across(-Year, mean))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
 aggregate(.~ Player.Name, subset(df, select = -Year), mean)
```